# Audio Mixer Circuit with Individual Volume

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, mixer, stereo

I'm trying to make an audio mixer circuit based on [the amplifier circuit published by Scott Campbell](https://www.circuitbasics.com/build-a-great-sounding-audio-amplifier-with-bass-boost-from-the-lm386).

I have no knowledge of opamps so I'm taking it mostly as-is but the input signal I am going to feed it with must be mixed from 2 different sources: the first one is a mono mixdown of a stereo source, while the second one is a mono source.

[image: Circuit]

I would like to be able to control the volume of the two sources separately (while the relative volumes of the stereo mixdown can be fixed), so my questions are:

1. Is the stereo-to-mono "circuit" correct?
2. Can I just put the RV2 pot like that? Are the values of R8, R9, RV2 ok?
3. Will setting RV1 or RV2 to zero cause a "jump" in the volume of the other source? If yes, can i put a small resistor in series with the pots in order to avoid this effect? How small?
4. Is R27 needed?
5. Do I need a series cap between the mixing point and the opamp positive input? (Note that the input signals already have a series cap each before they get to this circuit)

And, most importantly:
6. Will the circuit work as a whole?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

OK, I understand that the above circuit has issues, so I've switched to the following one, based on the TLC272 opamp, since I have some laying around:

[image: New circuit]

Does this make more sense? New questions:

7. Would this work?
8. Can R25 be safely removed?
9. Is 470k a sensible value for R28?
10. I am powering the opamp with a single 5V supply, is it correct to ground the positive input or do I have to bias it at 2.5V?

Comment: This won't be a very effective mixer. you need to use a proper inverting mixer to do the job correctly and more accurately. Se this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/268547/inverting-summing-amplifier-vs-non-inverting-summing-amplfier/268558#268558

Comment: Thanks, but note that my sources are fixed, they cannot be disconnected.

Comment: Shouldn't be the RV's connected the other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *6. Will the circuit work as a whole?*

You will get severe volume interactions between the two channels when you adjust their individual pots. For instance if adc_out is not required to me in the mix then you would adjust RV1 to ground the wiper but, unfortunately, this will also ground the wanted mixed_mono signal. Result: total interaction and not really a mixer.

> *3. Will setting RV1 or RV2 to zero cause a "jump" in the volume of the
> other source? If yes, can i put a small resistor in series with the
> pots in order to avoid this effect? How small?*

It may need to be as high as 100 kΩ to overcome the problem and, you might start to hear a little resistor noise.

> *1. Is the stereo-to-mono "circuit" correct?*

Yes, that will suffice.

> *Are the values of R8, R9, RV2 ok?*

They are OK.

> *Is R27 needed?*

If you didn't have it then when RV1 volume was turned fully up it would kill-off the mixed_mono signal.

I strongly suggest that you to use a proper mixer circuit using an inverting op-amp and forget this cranky method.

---

> *8. Can R25 be safely removed?*

> *9. Is 470k a sensible value for R28?*

> *10. I am powering the opamp with a single 5V supply, is it correct to ground the positive input or do I have to bias it at 2.5V?*

Yes to questions 8 and 9 but, for question 10, you need a dual rail supply for the op-amp or, use a 2.5 volt bias and add coupling capacitors connected in series with the potentiometer wipers.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the original question with an update circuit, could you please have a look?

Comment: Yes that's the best way forward but, for audio you don't need an extra inverting stage.

Comment: Ok, but the package has 2 amps anyway, I just thought I'd put the 2nd one to some use. Thanks!

Comment: @SukkoPera if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: If you can please have a look at questions 8, 9 and 10 I guess we're done :)

Comment: @SukkoPera added to answer

Comment: Thanks again. Just to be clear about question 10, do you mean it's ok to ground it?

Comment: @SukkoPera no it isn't. You need to have a dual supply that provides positive and negative voltages to make this work. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, do I need the caps in series with the wipers even if I already have series caps before the inputs shown here?

Comment: @SukkoPera yes because the potentiometer provides a resistance to ground/0 volts.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheets for the TL072 recommends a power supply that is minimum 10V total because the input must never be within 4V from the negative supply. Usually a positive 5V and a negative 5V is used with the inputs biased at 0V.

Your 220uF output capacitor is calculated for a 32 ohms speaker. The TL072 cannot drive a speaker so a 1uF capacitor should be used. The 220uF capacitor will take 10 seconds to charge.

Comment: Thanks, but I will be using a TLC272, not a TL072.

Comment: I have never used a TLC272 because it is Cmos with a high noise level. With a +5V supply, the +inputs of both opamps must be biased from a filtered +2V because the inputs on most of them do not work if higher than 4V.

Comment: I see, is there another opamp that would work with a single 5V supply that you'd recommend for this circuit? What about OPA2134PA for instance?

Comment: The OPA134 works very well with a supply that is 30V. As most opamps, with a 5V supply the max output level (about 1V RMS) will be very low nit then it an drive a power amplifier that is using a higher supply voltage.